# Deleting multiple columns in different data sets in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm wondering if there is a good way to delete multiple columns over a few different data sets in R.  I have a data set that looks like:

```
RangeNumber    Time    Value    Quality    Approval
          1    2:00        1          1           1
          2    2:05        4          2           1
```

And I want to delete everything but the Time and Value columns in my data sets.  I'm "deleting" them by setting each column to NULL, e.x.: `data1$RangeNumber <- NULL`.

I'm going to have upwards of 16 or more data sets with identical column setups, and data sets are going to be numbered in incremental order, e.x.: data1, data2, data3, &c.

I'm wondering if a `for` loop that iterates through all of the data set columns is the best way to accomplish this, or -- since I have read that R is slow at `for` loops--  if there is an easier way to do this.  I'm also wondering if I need to combine all of my data sets into one variable, and then iterate through to remove the columns.

If a `for` loop is the best way to go, how would I set it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to gather those dataframes into a list and then run the Extract function over them. The first argument given to "[" should be TRUE so that all rows are obtained, and the second argument should be the column names (I made up three dataframes that varied in their row numbers and column names but all had 'Time' and 'Value' columns:

```
> datlist <- list(dat1,dat2,dat3)
> TimVal <- lapply(datlist, "[", TRUE, c("Time","Value") )
> TimVal
[[1]]
  Time Value
1 2:00     1
2 2:05     4

[[2]]
  Time Value
1 2:00     1
2 2:05     4

[[3]]
    Time Value
1   2:00     1
2   2:05     4
2.1 2:05     4
1.1 2:00     1
```

This is added in case the goal was to have them all together in the same dataframe:

```
> do.call(rbind, TimVal)
    Time Value
1   2:00     1
2   2:05     4
3   2:00     1
4   2:05     4
11  2:00     1
21  2:05     4
2.1 2:05     4
1.1 2:00     1
```

If you are very new to R you may not have figured out that the last code did not change TimVal; it only showed what value would be returned and to make the effect durable you would need to assign to a name. Perhaps even the same name:

```
TimVal <- do.call(rbind, TimVal):
```

Comment: @qmoog, if you anticipate having to perform the same calculations across all of your 16 or more datasets, I also recommend this approach. Having a `list` of your `data.frame`s can be very convenient in such scenarios.

Comment: This seems to be a good approach.  I'm going to give this a try right now.

Comment: This is a good answer because it not only allows me to select the columns I need, but I can run another function in the data list to set the other columns to `NULL`.  Thanks to both @mrdwab and @DWin

Comment: I came across this solution while facing a similar problem, I would like to learn what is the role of the `[` in the `lapply(datlist, "[", TRUE, c("Time","Value") )` ?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than delete, just choose the columns that you want, i.e.

```
data1 = data1[, c(2, 3)]
```

The question still remains about your other data sets: `data2`, etc. I suspect that since your data frames are all "similar", you could combine them into a single data frame with an additional identifier column, `id`, which tells you the data set number. How you combine your data sets depends on how you data is stored. But typically, a `for` loop over `read.csv` is the way to go.

Comment: Since I'm expecting most data frames to have ~50000 rows of data, I'm trying to be conscious of memory usage by deleting what I don't need.  I like the idea of a `id` column if I do decide to combine them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I should recommend these since these are pretty "destructive" methods.... Be sure that you have a backup of your original data before trying ;-)

This approach assumes that the datasets are already in your workspace and you just want new versions of them.

Both of these are pretty much the same. One option uses `lapply()` and the other uses `for`.

- `lapply`

  ```
  lapply(ls(pattern = "data[0-9+]"),
         function(x) { assign(x, get(x)[2:3], envir = .GlobalEnv) })
  ```
- `for`

  ```
  temp <- ls(pattern = "data[0-9+]")
  for (i in 1:length(temp)) {
    assign(temp[i], get(temp[i])[2:3])
  }
  ```

Basically, `ls(.etc.)` will create a vector of datasets in your workspace matching the naming pattern you provide. Then, you write a small function to select the columns you want to keep.

A less "destructive" approach would be to create new `data.frame`s instead of overwriting the original ones. Something like this should do the trick:

```
lapply(ls(pattern = "data[0-9+]"),
       function(x) { assign(paste(x, "T", sep="."), 
                            get(x)[2:3], envir = .GlobalEnv) })
```

Comment: That's a fair point about making a copy.  My data is coming from a read-only source, so there's no worry about deleting the extraneous columns.

Comment: @qmoog, OK. As I mentioned in my answer, I had assumed from the way your question was stated that the datasets were already in your workspace, hence this suggested approach.

Comment: No worries.  I should have mentioned that in my original question.