# Deleting multiple rows in different data sets in R

Tags: r

I am working with multiple `data.frames` and I encountered problem when I want to delete specific rows in all of the `data.frames`. My problem is similar to the one posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499094/deleting-multiple-columns-in-different-data-sets-in-r), but I cannot make it work on the rows:

```
lst <- list(dat1,dat2)
lapply(lst,`[`, !="A", TRUE)
```

Assuming my tables look like this and there are multiple row names so it is not possible to extract all but A by `c("B", "C","D", ...)`:

---

```
|   | 1 | 2 | 3 | 
|---|---|---|---|
| A |   |   |   | 
| B |   |   |   |
| A |   |   |   |

|   | 1 | 2 | 3 | 
|---|---|---|---|
| C |   |   |   | 
| A |   |   |   |
| A |   |   |   |
```

---

I would be grateful for any help! Thanks

Comment: Did you try using an anonymous function?

Comment: `lapply(lst, function(x) x[ x[,1]!="A", ])`? (Illustrating an anonymous function...)

Comment: @Frank, I think they meant `lapply(lst, function(x) x[rownames(x) != "A", ])`

Comment: Great! It works, thank you very much! I did not think about anonymous function. Yes, the function should be adapted to all of the columns not only first one, but I figured that out.

Comment: It works but I do not understand why it also adds NA values to my data.frames. I am using following code `lapply(lst, function(x) x[ x!="A", c(-2)])` to also delete second row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use more complicated functions in an `*apply` call it's often useful or even necessary to use anonymous functions. The advantage is that you can build that function that is supposed to be applied to every list element (here, data.frames) just like you would do it in the case of a single data.frame.

If you wanted to subset rows of a regular data.frame by rownames you would use something like

```
mtcars[rownames(mtcars) != "Mazda RX4", ]
```

And in your `lapply` call you will do it the same way using an anonymous function where `x` represents each list element:

```
lapply(lst, function(x) x[rownames(x) != "A", ])
```